Mui popover, disable closing when clicking outside
I am using Mui Popover with ReactJS,
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/
when the user click with his mouse outside the popover it closes,
how can I disable this behavior and add a button with "save configuration" that only on click on this button will close the popover?

All you need to do is to adjust the value of the open property, you're giving the Popover component.
Instead of inverting its value, when the onClose event fires, only change its value after a click on your custom button.
I adjusted the example code of Basic Popover from https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/ to change its behaviour:


import * as React from 'react';
import Popover from '@mui/material/Popover';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function BasicPopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    toggleOpen();
  };

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const id = open ? 'simple-popover' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={() => undefined}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'center',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Button onClick={toggleOpen}>
        <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>Close</Typography>
        </Button>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}



